# Accessing 'this' context with a multi-level jQuery Plugin function

Tags: jquery

I have a multi-level plugin I would like to define:

```
$.fn.module = {};
$.fn.module.myfunc = function() { console.log(this); }
```

So I can call it with:

```
$(el).module.myfunc();
```

However, once I reach `myfunc`, the context variable `this` is no longer defined and I cannot access the selected element (`$(el)`).

Is there a way to access `$(el)` from inside `myfunc`?

Comment: is submodule supposed to be myFunc ?

Comment: Yes sorry; fixed that now :)

Answer (score 0):

Store 'this' into some variable and next time pass that variable to myfunc()